# About Modeling, Models

Tags: halal-haram, drawing

I'm muslim and I'm so proud of being muslim on this world. I have some simple questions which that never answered before. I'm a student and I still don't have a job because I'm Studying. Anyway, here is my questions...

1-I'm into arts and language, I love fashion and desing too. I sometimes look to female models to keep up with latest trends (I'm a boy) and fine arts, photography. But sometimes I saw some models that they're wearing transparent clothes to highlight the overall looking (companies want, and They're trying to show the natural body) and when i saw, I really really don't get affected (about sexual and bad things, bad humour) I'm just rating the model and his look with her clothes and I Save them to my collection (which I will draw all of them, I like it and this don't affects me sexually, I love this perk I have) does it harm? (I'm not a pervert, I'm Just trying to build a future job, an opportunity to myself)

2- What about nude modelling? I saw once but when I saw, I'm turning my glance to the other side of model (because I don't know if it is harm or not, and I'm also not effected by models, they're just making composition) does it harm to look at them? Because I'm trying to understand the shapes, heights, anatomy and naturality of women and other stuff (this is not effects me sexual, never effected me) so can I look them and get inspired for my projects and work? Thank Y'all! ( ps: I'm not trying to alter Islam to fit into something, I love Islam and those content is not affect me sexual - I mentioned above.)

Answer (score 1):

It is not allowed for a man to look at a woman. Allah says:

> Tell the believing men to reduce [some] of their vision and guard their private parts. That is purer for them. Indeed, Allah is Acquainted with what they do. (24:30)

It would not be allowed for you to look at women clothed in completely Islamic clothing, and it would obviously not be allowed if they are not clothed in Islamic clothing. And definitely not naked A'oozobillah!

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps you could love spelling and writing well too?

Dressing well is approved of in Islam and this is what fashion is actually about in Islam, rather than the excessive and sexualised  way it is thought of, say in French 'high couture', and which has spread and 'colonised' the world due to the prominence the 'image' has in modern world.